# Aurelia hook into router before app.js

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

So the aurelia app gets bootstrapped from the `main.js`

```
bootstrap(function(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('app', document.body));
});
```

The source code tells me there is a `router()` method you can call on the `FrameworkConfiguration` which is what `aurelia.use` gives you.

But the implementation gives you no hooks, it just includes the `framework-templating-router`.

The reason I want a hook in, is because I want to do an api call in the `activate()` of the `app.js` however, I wish to slide in a Navigation Pipeline middleware before the api call is made.

`configureRouter` is called after `activate()` which is obvious. This means I can dynamically inject menu items (api behind authorised walls) to build up my initial screen. If I get a `401` it rejects the `activate()` promise - which I want - however what would be better is if the pipeline step could `Redirect('login')`.

If I were to put custom login the `activate()` then I would have two places of redirection, but also it just doesn't fit into the aurelia design very well.

There is an alternative solution which is to defer configuring the router till a child view of the `app.js` but it doesn't seem as nice.

Comment: Before posting a possible answer to your question....is there any reason that you can't configure the router in the app.js constructor? You don't have to use the `configureRouter` method at all.

Comment: oh really?! is that possible

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung and if I do a `router.navigateToRoute('')` in the `activate` of app, will it route properly

Comment: Yes, it's possible. App.js can look like any other viewmodel in your application - constructor, activate, etc. In the skeleton, it just uses configureRouter as an example. Just inject the router as you usually would and configure it in your constructor. NavigateToRoute should work in the activate call, yes - but I think you have to return it.

Comment: my current implementation doesn't return it, and as I read the comments surrounding the source code, it appears it takes hold of the navigation and commands it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js, you can do this:

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class App {
    constructor (router) {
        this.router = router;
        this.router.configure(config => ...);
    }

    activate () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Essentially....you don't have to use the `configureRouter` method. It's just there as a convenience. Using the constructor allows more flexibility in this case.